# How to find a combination of two columns that is NOT in the other table in ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, exists

I have a main table that contains the data I have, and a reference table telling me what values the main table should have. I want to check if the main table contains all required values, and if not, return the missing values.
My main table look like the following:

```
ID ORG DSIT
-----------
1  A   AA
1  B   BB
2  A   AA
2  B   BB
2  C   CC
```

and my reference table looks like:

```
ORG DSIT
---------
A   AA
B   BB
C   CC
```

That means for each ID in main table, it should have 3 columns with (ORG, DSIT) = (A,AA), (B,BB) and (C,CC) base on the reference table. Thus, here ID 2 is ok, but ID 1 is missing a (C,CC) combination for ORG and DSIT

I have try left join, by doing so I can get that (C,CC) is missing but cannot tell which ID it belongs to. I also try NOT EXIST but it just not work in this way.

I am expect to see the result:

```
ID ORG DSIT
-----------
1  C   CC
```

OR

```
ID  MESSAGE
-----------
1   'C and CC is missing'
```

Thanks in advance; and let me know if I can explain it better.

Comment: which version of oracle are you using?

Comment: I recommend creating a surrogate key for your reference table so it's easier to do what you are trying to do. An example would be to concatenate ORG and DSIT. For example `A_AA` would be the key for (A, AA). Then on your main table you can calculate the key, perform a LEFT JOIN, and see where there are NULLs. That's just one way.

Comment: @drum Thank you so much for the opinion. However, let's say I concatenate ORG and DSIT for both tables, if I do main LEFT JOIN reference, then we will not get NULLs. If I do reference LEFT JOIN main, then I will get NULL on ID with CC_CC (base on my example), but in this case I do not know what ID is missing CC_CC. Please correct me if I miss something here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  maint (id, org, dsit) as
  3    (select 1, 'A', 'AA' from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'B', 'BB' from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'A', 'AA' from dual union all
  6     select 2, 'B', 'BB' from dual union all
  7     select 2, 'C', 'CC' from dual
  8    ),
  9  reft (org, dsit) as
 10    (select 'A', 'AA' from dual union all
 11     select 'B', 'BB' from dual union all
 12     select 'C', 'CC' from dual
 13    )
```

Query begins here; it uses the `minus` set operator which returns the *difference* between two sets: one is all values you expect, and one is all values you have. Difference is what you're missing.

```
 14  -- all values you expect
 15  select b.id, r.org, r.dsit
 16  from (select distinct m.id from maint m) b cross join reft r
 17  minus
 18  -- all values you have
 19  select a.id, a.org, a.dsit
 20  from maint a;

        ID ORG DSIT
---------- --- ----
         1 C   CC

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

A set operation like MINUS may be costly on large data sets, in that case you may try:

```
select
    id, org, dsit
from (
    select id from maint
    group by id having(count(*) < (select count(*) from reft))
) g
cross join reft r
where not exists(
    select 1 from maint m where r.org = m.org and r.dsit = m.dsit
        and g.id = m.id
)
;
```